# Apache POI - image not displaying in Microsoft Excel

Tags: java, image, spring-boot, apache-poi

I am using apache poi to generate Excel sheet, where I want to include the company logo on top-left corner.

I have used the below given code to get image from URL and add it to first cell. As I tested, it's not working in Microsoft office, Libre office **but working in Mac's Numbers**

Code:

```
private void setOrganisationLogo(HSSFWorkbook workbook, HSSFSheet sheet) {
int pictureIdx = 0;
try {
  String orgUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
  InputStream inputStream = new URL(orgUrl).openStream();
  byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
  pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
  inputStream.close();
  CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
  ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
  anchor.setCol1(1);
  anchor.setRow1(1);
  Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

  drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Images-N10426. Either you are using `pict.resize();` as in this example. Or you must using a two cells anchor like `anchor.setCol1(1); anchor.setRow1(1); anchor.setCol2(2); anchor.setRow2(4);` for example to determine the pictures size through the anchor.

Comment: Adding two cell anchor worked for me. Thanks